# How to match subplot ranges in mplfinance

Tags: mplfinance

When drawing the RSI, I am thinking of drawing the 25% and 75% horizontal lines.
With automatic range adjustment, the 25% line is displayed as a separate axis on the right side from 20 to 30.
I can use ylim=() to adjust the range and it works fine, but it still doesn't combine the 75% on the left side with the RSI axis, and the scale is displayed on the right side, which is not smart.
Is there a better way to do this?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `hlines` or `mpf.make_addplot()` to draw your 25% and 75% lines?
It sounds like you are using `mpf.make_addplot()` (otherwise the `hlines` would be drawn on the same axis as the prices).

If so, when calling `mpf.make_addplot()` use kwarg `secondary_y`.

As explained between cells `In [15]` and `In [16]` in the [**addplot tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb) ...

- `mpf.make_addplot()` has a keyword argument called `secondary_y` which can have three possible values: `True`, `False`, and `'auto'`.

  - The default value is `'auto'` which means if you don't specify `secondary_y`, or if you specify `secondary_y='auto'`, then `mpf.plot()` will attempt to decide whether a secondary y-axis is needed, by comparing the order of magnitude of the addplot data with the order of magnitude of the data that is already on the plot.
  - If `mpf.plot()` gets it wrong, you can always override by setting `secondary_y=True` or `secondary_y=False`.